# Regex match first characters of string

Tags: regex

I am trying to create a regex that will match the first 3 characters of a string,

If I have a string ABCFFFF I want to verify that the first 3 characters are ABC.

Comment: Getting the first 3 characters of a string is not a good usage of Regular Expressions. Either way, what technology are you using?

Comment: I definitely wouldn't do this with regex, simple string comparison would be easier to read and give better performance.

Comment: I don't think the critism is deserved, when learning things it is good to start with the simplest examples

Answer (score 24, accepted):

It's pretty straightforward, the pattern would be `^ABC`

As others may point out, using regular expressions for such a task is an overkill. Any programming language with regex support can do it better with simple string manipulations.

Answer (score 9):

Just simple regex will work:

```
/^ABC/
```

But is it a good use case for using regex, I am not sure. Consider using `substring` in whatever language/platform you're using.

Answer (score 0):

"^ABC" should work.  '^' matches the start in most regex implementations.